# Running a Coldfusion function server side from a link

Tags: function, coldfusion

I have a cfm page which includes a function and runs the function based on some arguments passed to the page as url variables.  My requirement is to call the page via a hyperlink/button but not open the page in the browser.  The client browser must remain on the page with the hyperlink/button.

To clarify a bit more:

I have a ringout.cfm page with the following code:

```
<cfinclude template="/functions/easySocket.cfm">
<cfset NL = chr(13) & chr(10) />
<cfset extension = #url.user_extension#>
<cfset outbound_line=#url.partner_line#>
<cfset target_number=#url.target_number#>
<cfset call_type="from-internal">
<cfset call_id="12345">
<cfset caller_id="Blah Blah">
<cfset APICommand="Action: Login#NL#Username: tst#NL#Secret: tst#NL##NL#Action: Originate#NL#Channel: PJSIP/#extension##NL#Exten: #outbound_line##target_number##NL#Context: #call_type##NL#Priority: 1#NL#Callerid: #caller_id##NL#ActionID: #call_id##NL#Async: true#NL##NL#">
<cfoutput>
#easySocket('222.222.xx.xx','5038', APICommand)#
</cfoutput>
```

I would like to call the above page from within another page (contacts.cfm) without leaving the page.  I have the following code in my contacts.cfm:

```
<a href="#buildUrl("crm.ringout")#&target_number=<cfoutput>#reReplace(#contact_mobile#, "[[:space:]]", "", "ALL")#</cfoutput>&partner_line=302&user_extension=204" runat="server">#contact_mobile#&nbsp</a>
```

All I would like to do is run the ringout.cfm page server side.

Comment: Seems like a good place to use a very tiny iframe.

Comment: 1. runat="server" makes not sense in the CF world. 2. I see `buildURL` Are you using FW/1?

Comment: Hint: You'll need to use ajax. Running server side code from the client (ie link, button, etc) requires opening a a new http request. To do that without leaving the page requires ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You have provided very little information and no code. But as I understand, you can do it. In your xxx.cfm add this code

```
<cfif structKeyExists(URL,"YOUR_URL_VAR")>
<!--- call your function here, generate the desired output and show as plain text/html or json format. Abort the processing if you know this variable will only exist for specific hyperlink/button call--->
  <cfabort>
</cfif>
```

Then with your link call xxx.cfm and pass the desired url variable along.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I have updated my question to provide some more information.